# How to make inside html table in php echo a normal contest

Tags: php, html

Well what i want to what is to add here

```
    echo "<td>" . $row["seller"] . "</td>";
```

I want to make it like this

```
echo "<td>" Seller : . $row["seller"] . "</td>";
```

But this gives me an error , how to correctly write it

Like the resultat be like

Seller : **and the value of the $row**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

```
 echo "<td> Seller: ". $row["seller"] . "</td>";
```

strings go inside `""` in PHP.

Or you can do it like this:

```
 echo '<td> Seller: '. $row["seller"] . '</td>';
```

`''` will transform anything inside it to their HTML equivalent since `""` treats everything inside it as a string.